Why does removing consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE from Feign client resolve my Keycloak token request?
I'm working with Feign in a Spring Boot application to integrate with Keycloak's token endpoint. I have the following Feign client setup to request an access token:
@FeignClient(name = "auth-service", url = "${keycloak.auth-server-url}/realms")
public interface KeyCloakAuthServiceClient {

    @PostMapping(value = "/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    AccessTokenResponse getAccessToken(@PathVariable("realm") String realm,
                                       MultiValueMap<String, String> formParams);

    class Configuration {
        @Bean
        Encoder feignFormEncoder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> converters) {
            return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(converters));
        }
    }
}

Issue:
This setup was consistently failing to communicate with Keycloak's token endpoint, even though I was passing the necessary parameters in a MultiValueMap. However, once I removed the consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE from the @PostMapping annotation, everything started working and I was able to receive the token.
Question:
Why does Feign fail to process the request when consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE is included in the @PostMapping annotation, and why does it work when I remove it, even though the content type is still application/x-www-form-urlencoded? Is there a conflict between the consumes attribute and the @Headers annotation, or could this be a different issue?
Any insights on why this happens or what I might be missing would be appreciated!
What did you try?
I initially added consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE to the @PostMapping annotation, expecting it to correctly set the content type for the form-encoded request. I also added the @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded") annotation to ensure the proper content type was sent in the request.
I verified that the MultiValueMap contains all required form parameters like client_id, grant_type, username, password, etc. However, the request consistently failed, and I couldn’t retrieve the token from Keycloak.
Then, I removed the consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE part, and to my surprise, the request worked perfectly, and I received the access token from Keycloak.
What were you expecting?
I expected the Feign client to work with both consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE in the @PostMapping annotation and the @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), as this should instruct Feign to send a form-encoded request to the token endpoint. However, it only worked after removing the consumes attribute, which I didn’t expect.

consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE should already set the Content-Type type header to the requests sent by the @FeignClient.
Maybe are you just ending with duplicate header?
You should try removing @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), keeping just the @PostMapping.
